# Click a webpage element which under another element by using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, google-chrome-extension, web-applications

```
<div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="tbis-div"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" tabindex="0" class="hidden-xs" aria-label="2. Result for and displayed for your query"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c102=""> 2 Results for <strong _ngcontent-tbs-c102=""> HOWRAH JN <span _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> SURAT | Sat, 05 Nov 2022 </strong> For Quota | Tatkal </span></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="hidden-xs col-xs-12 clearfix" style="margin-top: 2px;"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102=""><span _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="pull-left"><p-menu _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="ng-tns-c96-18"><!----></p-menu><button _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" type="button" class="active btnDefault"> Sort By <span _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="hidden-xs">| Duration</span></button><button _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" type="button" class="btnDefault ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="hidden-xs">Show Available Trains</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">Available</span></button><!----></span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="pull-right"><button _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" type="button" class="btnDefault hidden-xs"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span> Previous Day </button><button _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" type="button" class="btnDefault hidden-xs"> Next Day <span _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></button><span _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="fa fa-filter hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" style="font-size: 3rem; padding-right: 6px;"></span></span></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix" style="margin-top: 15px;"></div><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="form-group no-pad col-xs-12 bull-back border-all"><app-train-avl-enq _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" _nghost-tbs-c101=""><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="dull-back no-pad col-xs-12"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="train-type train-type-SP"></span><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-sm-5 col-xs-11 train-heading"><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><!----> SHM PBR SUF EXP (12906)</strong></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-sm-7 col-xs-1" style="margin-top: 7px; font-size: initial;"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-left hidden-xs"> Runs On: <span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="N">M</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="N">T</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="N">W</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="N">T</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">F</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">S</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="N">S</span></span><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right"><!----><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" tabindex="0" class="a"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="hidden-xs ng-star-inserted">Train Schedule</span><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm fa fa-map-marker" style="font-size: 2.6rem;"></span></span></strong></div></div></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="white-back no-pad col-xs-12" style="padding: 12px 0;"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-5 hidden-xs"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="time"><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">21:00 | </strong></span> SHALIMAR | Sat, 05 Nov </div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-7 hidden-xs"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-3 pull-left line-hr"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">29:17</span></span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right"><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="time">02:17 | </strong> SURAT | Mon, 07 Nov</span></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><!----></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="time col-xs-4">21:00</div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-4 line-hr"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">29:17</span></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-4"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right time">02:17</span></div></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-left">SHALIMAR</div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right">SURAT</div></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-4">Sat, 05 Nov</div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="remove-padding col-xs-4 text-center" style="top: -6px; text-align: center;"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="N">M</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="N">T</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="N">W</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="N">T</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">F</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">S</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="N">S</span></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-4 pull-right"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right">Mon, 07 Nov</span></div></div></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="white-back col-xs-12 ng-star-inserted" style="overflow-x: auto;"><table _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><tr _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><td _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" style="padding-right: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" tabindex="0" class="pre-avl"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">Sleeper (SL)</strong></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 link" style="padding: 5px 0;"> Refresh <span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="fa fa-repeat" style="font-size: 2rem;"></span></div></div></td><td _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" style="padding-right: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" tabindex="0" class="pre-avl"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">AC 3 Tier (3A)</strong></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 link" style="padding: 5px 0;"> Refresh <span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="fa fa-repeat" style="font-size: 2rem;"></span></div></div></td><td _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" style="padding-right: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" tabindex="0" class="pre-avl"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">AC 2 Tier (2A)</strong></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 link" style="padding: 5px 0;"> Refresh <span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="fa fa-repeat" style="font-size: 2rem;"></span></div></div></td><td _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" style="padding-right: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" tabindex="0" class="pre-avl"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">AC First Class (1A) </strong></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 link" style="padding: 5px 0;"> Refresh <span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="fa fa-repeat" style="font-size: 2rem;"></span></div></div></td><!----></tr></table></div><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" avllazyload="" rel="preload"></div></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="dull-back no-pad"><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><!----><!----></div></div><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 20px;"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" style="overflow-x: auto;"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-left"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><button _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" type="button" class="btnDefault disable-book train_Search ng-star-inserted"> Book Now </button><!----><button _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" type="button" class="btnDefault ng-star-inserted" id="T_12906"> OTHER DATES </button><!----><!----></span><!----></span><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm link"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></span><!----></div></div></div><p-overlaypanel _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" appendto="body" class="ng-tns-c97-32"><!----></p-overlaypanel><p-overlaypanel _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" appendto="body" class="ng-tns-c97-33"><!----></p-overlaypanel></app-train-avl-enq></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="text-center form-group" id="div-gpt-ad-5906987-0" style=""><div id="google_ads_iframe_/37179215/GPT_NWEB_TRAIN_LIST_TOP_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none; width: 970px; height: 0px;"></div></div><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="text-center ng-star-inserted" id="trainAds_1_12906"></div><!----></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="form-group no-pad col-xs-12 bull-back border-all"><app-train-avl-enq _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" _nghost-tbs-c101=""><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="dull-back no-pad col-xs-12"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="train-type train-type-SP"></span><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-sm-5 col-xs-11 train-heading"><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" style="" xpath="1"><!----> HWH ADI SUF EXP (12834)</strong></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-sm-7 col-xs-1" style="margin-top: 7px; font-size: initial;"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-left hidden-xs"> Runs On: <span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">M</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">T</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">W</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">T</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">F</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">S</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">S</span></span><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right"><!----><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" tabindex="0" class="a"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="hidden-xs ng-star-inserted">Train Schedule</span><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm fa fa-map-marker" style="font-size: 2.6rem;"></span></span></strong></div></div></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="white-back no-pad col-xs-12" style="padding: 12px 0;"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-5 hidden-xs"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="time"><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">23:40 | </strong></span> HOWRAH JN | Sat, 05 Nov </div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-7 hidden-xs"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-3 pull-left line-hr"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">32:22</span></span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right"><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="time">08:02 | </strong> SURAT | Mon, 07 Nov</span></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><!----></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="time col-xs-4">23:40</div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-4 line-hr"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">32:22</span></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-4"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right time">08:02</span></div></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-left">HOWRAH JN</div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right">SURAT</div></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-4">Sat, 05 Nov</div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="remove-padding col-xs-4 text-center" style="top: -6px; text-align: center;"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">M</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">T</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">W</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">T</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">F</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">S</span><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="Y">S</span></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-4 pull-right"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right">Mon, 07 Nov</span></div></div></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="white-back col-xs-12 ng-star-inserted" style="overflow-x: auto;"><table _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><tr _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><td _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" style="padding-right: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" tabindex="0" class="pre-avl"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">Sleeper (SL)</strong></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 link" style="padding: 5px 0;"> Refresh <span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="fa fa-repeat" style="font-size: 2rem;"></span></div></div></td><td _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" style="padding-right: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" tabindex="0" class="pre-avl"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">AC 3 Tier (3A)</strong></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 link" style="padding: 5px 0;"> Refresh <span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="fa fa-repeat" style="font-size: 2rem;"></span></div></div></td><td _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" style="padding-right: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" tabindex="0" class="pre-avl"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><strong _ngcontent-tbs-c101="">AC 2 Tier (2A)</strong></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 link" style="padding: 5px 0;"> Refresh <span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="fa fa-repeat" style="font-size: 2rem;"></span></div></div></td><!----></tr></table></div><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" avllazyload="" rel="preload"></div></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="dull-back no-pad"><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix"></div><!----><!----></div></div><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 20px;"><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" style="overflow-x: auto;"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-left"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101=""><button _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" type="button" class="btnDefault disable-book train_Search ng-star-inserted"> Book Now </button><!----><button _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" type="button" class="btnDefault ng-star-inserted" id="T_12834"> OTHER DATES </button><!----><!----></span><!----></span><div _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="pull-right hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm link"><span _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></span><!----></div></div></div><p-overlaypanel _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" appendto="body" class="ng-tns-c97-34"><!----></p-overlaypanel><p-overlaypanel _ngcontent-tbs-c101="" appendto="body" class="ng-tns-c97-35"><!----></p-overlaypanel></app-train-avl-enq></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="text-center form-group" id="div-gpt-ad-5906987-0"></div><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="text-center ng-star-inserted" id="trainAds_1_12834"></div><!----></div><!----></div><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix" style="margin-top: 5px;"></div><!----><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="col-xs-12 clearfix" style="margin-top: 5px;"></div><div _ngcontent-tbs-c102="" class="text-center form-group" id="div-gpt-ad-5906988-0" style=""><div id="google_ads_iframe_/37179215/GPT_NWEB_TRAIN_LIST_BOTTOM_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none; width: 970px; height: 0px;"></div></div><div id="adContainer1" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: fit-content; border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 12px; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px; column-gap: 30px; margin: 25px auto;">
 
         <span>
         
       </span>
 
           <div id="div-gpt-ad-1664429992698-0"><script>
       googletag.cmd.push(function () {
         googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-1664429992698-0");
       });
 </script></div>
           <div id="div-ub-irctc" style="margin:0; max-width:400px; max-height:280px; overflow:hidden;"><div id="unibots-video"></div></div>
           <div id="div-gpt-ad-1664430029564-0"><script>
       googletag.cmd.push(function () {
         googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-1664430029564-0");
       });
 </script></div>
 
           <span>
           
         </span>
 
           </div></div>
```

I want to click webpage element by above mentioned source
like there's is 2, 3 element(train no exaample 12834) and each of those have individual element(example sl, 2A, 3A)
I want to click individual train class like below
**clicktrainclass(12834, "SL");**
Please help me to do this

Comment: full source available here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X9nKnJgc9BAXXjNPEZrEZ2qj1RGy6OkT/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Set that top div the CSS attribute `pointer-events: none`. Then you can click on the below div element.